# Model.aggregate gives me different results as in the mongo console (none for mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

When I execute the following in the console I get one nameID and a min max.

```
db.prices.aggregate([
  {"$match":{ nameID: { '$in': [ ObjectId('longid') ] } } }//replaced the actual value with longid
  ,{"$group":{"_id":"$nameID","nameID":{"$first": "$nameID"} ,"min":{"$min":"$price"},"max":{"$max":"$price"}}}
  ,{"$sort":{"min":1}}
  ,{"$limit":5}
])
```

When in mongoose I get an empty array:

```
Price.aggregate([
  {"$match":{ nameID: { '$in': [ 'longid' ] } }}//replaced the actual value with longid
  ,{"$group":{"_id":"$nameID","nameID":{"$first": "$nameID"} ,"min":{"$min":"$price"},"max":{"$max":"$price"}}}
  ,{"$sort":{"min":1}}
  ,{"$limit":5}
  ],function(){}//needs a callback passed or no promise is returned
).then(function(res){
  console.log('got a totals:',res);//res is [] here
  return Price.find({ nameID: { '$in': [ 'longid' ] } }}).exec();
}).then(function(res){
  console.log(res.length);//yes, got 3 records
  console.log(res[0]['price']);//yes, the price
```

Doing a Price.find with the query gets me 3 records.

Am I missing something or is this a known problem with mongoose?

**[UPDATE]**

With aggregate I cannot pass the id as a string so converted to ObjectId and it worked. Here is an example how:

```
 Price.aggregate([   
    {"$match":{ nameID: { '$in': [ 
        new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('longid')//replaced the actual value with longid
      ] 
    } 
 }}
 ...
```

Comment: Please just check this even if it seems obvious. Mongoose has a "pluralize" rule on models because it expects a general convention that you specify a model with a "singular" name context and the "collection" is a "pluralized" concept of the model name. It should be right, but please try: `mongoose.model( 'Prices', pricesSchema, 'prices' )` where the "third" argument there overrides as the actual collection name. Also please make sure you are connecting to the same database as expected.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for your comment, updated the model name. Doing a `.find` using the same query gets me the 3 records so I'm sore there are 3 records with the same nameID to group. Removing sort and limit didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Okay then. To be frank your `ObjectId('longId')` is pseudo code for the actual value. I suspect unless you are importing from `'mongodb.ObjectID`  as the basic driver concept for the function then you are importing `ObjectId` from mongoose, which does not do what you might expect. Therefore the problem here.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sorry; copy paste error. ObjectId is not used in mongoose, mongoose just passes a string but on the mongo command line ObjectId is needed to convert the string into a valid id. longid is a replacement for the 24 character id.

Comment: Yes I know that otherwise I would not have asked. Explanation. In "normal" queries, mongoose "inspects the schema" of the referenced model to see what "type" fields are an "autocasts". Son in a normal `.find()` an `_id` value supplied as a "string" will be cast to an `ObjectId` or whatever "type" that field is defined as in the schema. Under aggregation this cannot happen. There is a big difference between `Schema.Types.ObjectId` and the import from the core driver `mongodb.ObjectID`. Which one are you using to convert? Only the "latter" will actually work.

Comment: @NeilLunn did not convert. will try to use `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(longid)` as mongoose is the only thing available. It is injected as a dependency so need to change quite a lot of code to have monodb available unless mongoose exposes it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Problem solved, in my query builder I convert the string to ObjectID and it "works". Will update the questing with working code. Updated the question with a `.find` that actually does return 3 results but as you mentioned this may (and does) not work with aggregate.

Comment: Yeah well, posted that answer once you made it clear what you were actually doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oops. From your last comment to my last comment you have highlighted the problem here. Mongoose will "inspect" and convert "types" based on the applied schema to the model in most cases for operations. It cannot and "will not" do this in aggregation pipelines. So you need to do this:

```
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

var actual_hex_string; // as received from input parameters

// then
Price.aggregate([
    {"$match":{ 
         "nameID": { 
             "$in": [ ObjectID(actual_hex_string) ]
          }
    }}
    (...) // the rest of the pipeline
```

Also [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) seems not to be appropriate here unless you are intending to use an actual "array" of possible ( and already converted ) `ObjectID` values here. Don't make the common mistake of thinking "nameID" is an "array" therefore you must use `$in`. MongoDB does not care if this is an array or a single value. `$in` is for "multiple matches" in an `$or` context for the same field. A simple equality match works just as well for an "array" in the document.