# How do a pipeline using let with import models of mongoose js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, let

Im try to do a query on mongoose , that a im using a agregation with a $let a $pipeline but i cannot do referent to the fields of the model of my scheme and the query return undefined value . the colletions of schemas are imports files.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const BASCULE  = require('../models/BASCULE');
const USER  = require('../models/USER');
const USER_BASC  = require('../models/USER_BASC');
USER_BASC.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:{ 
                from: USER.collection.name, 
                let: { XXX: 'ID_USER' }, 
                pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $and: [ {$eq: [ "$DISABILITY", 'false'] }, 
                                             {$eq: [ "$ID", "$$XXX" ] } ] } }

                },
                {$project: { _id: 0 } }],

                as: 'INFO_USER' 
            },
        },
        {
            $match:{
                ID_BASC: req.params.id_0
            }
        },
        {
            $project: { _id: 0 } 
        }

]
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here, [Model.aggregate gives me different results as in the mongo console (none for mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982374/model-aggregate-gives-me-different-results-as-in-the-mongo-console-none-for-mon)

In mongoose framework for aggragate function, while matching with id you have to mention it is mongodb object id for reasons mentioned in the link.